# Getting the value of an attribute. Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, boolean, attr

**GOAL:** I want the valid icon to show when the input has a valid attribute of true.
and the invalid icon to show when it's false && the input has a length of 1 or more characters.

**(phoneInputs function):**
in the console, it outputs "incomplete" for every keypress until the length = 10.
When it reaches 10 characters, it says good and sets the valid attribute to true.

**(formCheck function):**
adds or removes a .hidden class depending upon the length.
(This is the part that isn't working because I'm trying to target the input's **valid** attribute. The attribute via the inspector seems to be working and functioning perfectly, via the phoneInputs function)

I've tried console.log() the following:

1. **input.target** - shows the correct input element.
2. **input.target.valid** - undefined
3. **input.target.getAttribute('valid')** - returns an error

Any help?

https://codepen.io/gold240sx/pen/wvyqPpP?editors=1111

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1758b3260f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
       .hidden {
          display: none;
       }
  </style>
  <script>
    const formCheck = (input) => {
       const chxVer = input.target.parentElement.querySelector('.bool-form-val')
       const validIco = chxVer.querySelector('.check')
       const invalidIco = chxVer.querySelector('.x')

       if (input.target.getAttribute("valid")==true) {
           validIco.classList.remove('hidden')
           invalidIco.classList.add('hidden')
       } else if (input.target.getAttribute("valid")==false) {
           input.target.setAttribute('valid', false)
           console.log(input.target.valid)
           validIco.classList.add('hidden')
           invalidIco.classList.remove('hidden')
       } else {}
       console.log(input.target.getAttribute("valid"))
   }

   const phoneInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.phone-number');
   phoneInputs.forEach((input) => {

       const boolFormChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.bool-form-val');

       input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    
           formCheck(e)
           //US numbers only
           if (input.value.length === 10) {
               input.setAttribute('valid', true)
               // console.log(input.target.isValid)
               console.log('phone number good')
               console.log(input.value) //Outputs final phone number
           } else {
              // console.log(input.validity.valid)
              input.setAttribute('valid', false)
              // console.log(input.value.length)
              console.log("incomplete")
           }
       })
    })
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input">
      <input 
         type="text"
         name="phoneNumber" 
         id="signup-phoneNumber" 
         placeholder="Phone Number" 
         class="icoinput phone-number" 
         maxlength="10"
      >
      <div class="bool-form-val">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check check hidden"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-square-x x hidden"></i>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: input.getAttribute('valid') ?

Comment: console.log(input.getAttribute('valid'))- Returns: TypeError: input.getAttribute is not a function. (In 'input.getAttribute('valid')', 'input.getAttribute' is undefined),... hence the target. EDIT: I should add, this is being inserted right above the if statement within the formCheck function.

Comment: @MichaelMartell You're calling `formCheck` before adding the attribute `valid` to the input. You need to place the function call **after** you set the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) always returns a `string` but you compare it with `true` and this comparison will always be false. **You should instead do `input.target.getAttribute("valid") == "true"`.**
   For the opposite check, you should just do it in the `else`, there's no need for a `input.target.getAttribute("valid") == "false"` (which won't work anyway since you never set the value to `false`).
2. You do `formCheck(e)` at the beginning of the `keyup` listener, before setting the `valid` attribute in the next lines. That means if you type the 10th character, you check the value of valid, which is still not true, and THEN since it's the 10th character you set it to true.
   **You should thus do `formCheck(e)` at the end of the function.**

Here's your code with the 2 fixes done:

```js
const formCheck = (input) => {
  const chxVer = input.target.parentElement.querySelector('.bool-form-val')
  const validIco = chxVer.querySelector('.check')
  const invalidIco = chxVer.querySelector('.x')

  if (input.target.getAttribute("valid") == "true") {
    validIco.classList.remove('hidden')
    invalidIco.classList.add('hidden')
  } else {
    input.target.setAttribute('valid', false)
    console.log(input.target.valid)
    validIco.classList.add('hidden')
    invalidIco.classList.remove('hidden')
  }
  console.log(input.target.getAttribute("valid"))
}

const phoneInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.phone-number');
phoneInputs.forEach((input) => {

  const boolFormChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.bool-form-val');

  input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {


    //US numbers only
    if (input.value.length === 10) {
      input.setAttribute('valid', true)
      // console.log(input.target.isValid)
      console.log('phone number good')
      console.log(input.value) //Outputs final phone number
    } else {
      // console.log(input.validity.valid)
      input.setAttribute('valid', false)
      // console.log(input.value.length)
      console.log("incomplete")
    }
    formCheck(e)

  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1758b3260f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="signup-phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" class="icoinput phone-number" maxlength="10">
    <div class="bool-form-val">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check check hidden"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-square-x x hidden"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `input.target.getAttribute("valid")==true` comparison usually succeed, since non-empty strings are truthy and it's not a strict comparison? Or do I need to be [whacked with a wet trout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3AWhacking_with_a_wet_trout)?

Comment: The [loose equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#loose_equality_using) (`==`) compares both value after converting them to a common type. For a string and a boolean, they are both converted to numbers before comparing. `Number("true")` is `NaN` and `Number(true)` is `1`. And since `NaN` is not equal to `1`, `"true"` is not equal to `true`.

Comment: Oh, huh. I guess I never realized "truthy" only means that `if (<truthy value>)` will succeed

Comment: Yes! You could also think of it like this: a value is truthy if `Boolean(value)` returns true!

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive explanation! getAttribute is new to me so this definitely, although seemingly minuscule, was a very important and wonderful thing to learn! Thank you so much for your time and help! <br><br> P.S. The whacked with a wet trout was funny as hell!